# Know which parts a day contains

Tags: python, date, datetime, date-parsing, dateparser

The [dateparser library](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) set missing parts of a date to today's values.

Example:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse("2015")
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 14, 0, 0)
```

How to know which parts a date really contains?

(and thus which parts were set to today's values by the library)?

This is what I've come up with.

Is there a more efficient way?

```
date_str = input('Type a date: ')

settings = {"REQUIRE_PARTS": ["year"]}
res = dateparser.parse(date_str, settings=settings)
if res is None:
    print("Invalid Date")
    return

settings = {"REQUIRE_PARTS": ["year", "month"]}
res = dateparser.parse(date_str, settings=settings)
if res is None:
    print("Date has year only")
    return
    
settings = {"REQUIRE_PARTS": ["year", "month", "day"]}
res = dateparser.parse(date_str, settings=settings)
if res is None:
    print("Date has year and month")
    return

print("Date has year, month and day")
```

Comment: not sure but I doubt the parser keeps track of the contained parts? It would be more straight-forward if you could use explicit formats, so you could use a simple mapping of 'contains' vs. format.

Comment: @FObersteiner what does it mean "use explicit formats"?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. By "format" I meant parsing directive.

Comment: @FObersteiner doesn't that imply discarding the `dateparser` library altogether?

Comment: yes, I know that's kind of a blunt suggestion - totally depends on the scope of your program if it's an option or not. If dateparser has no option to return what you need, you can still look at the [source code](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) and see if that gives you any idea how to implement it?